# MomentJS is reversing day and month in format()

Tags: momentjs

I'm using momentJS to format some dates for a chartJS implementation.

In the chart i'm predicting the next 15 minutes worth of data so need to add the next 15 minutess worth of datetimes to my chartLabel variable.

I use the below function to achieve this. The issue is that the formatting for every other datetime seems to reverse the day and month. I have no idea why this is happening, has anyone seen this before?

```
predictMarketData(){
    let lastDate = this.marketData[this.marketData.length-1][0]
    lastDate = moment.unix(lastDate).add(1, 'minutes').format('DD/MM h:mm a')

    for(var _i = 0; _i < 15; _i++){
       this.chartLabels.push(lastDate);
       lastDate = moment(lastDate).add(1, 'minutes').format('DD/MM h:mm a');
    }
}
```

It appears to add minutes correctly but the day month formatting appears to reverse every other, screenshot provided.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: the original time im getting for lastDate is in epoch format for now()

Comment: "... screenshot provided". Where's the screenshot?

Comment: can you add example input and output expected @user2249567

Comment: Sorry I've added the screen shot. You can see that past 09:26 the day and month starts to get flipped around every other entry.